# Reinitialising jQuery function after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am currently using a jQuery plugin that is applying a GreyScale hover effect. The plugin works perfectly.

The page the plugin is on utilises ajax based filtering. Because of this the below code only works correctly on the initial load. I need to be able to reinitialise both elements on each filter.

I having been experimenting with `$(document).on` as I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 but cannot get this working..

```
$(function() {
    // fade in the grayscaled images to avoid visual jump
    $('.colour img').hide().fadeIn(1000);
  });

  // user window.load to ensure images have been loaded
  $(window).load(function () {
    $('.colour img').greyScale({
      // call the plugin with non-defult fadeTime (default: 400ms)
      fadeTime: 500,
      reverse: false
    });
  });
```

Comment: which plugin and can you share some more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just put it in a function, call that function in document ready and then call it again after your ajax call? Something like:

```
function YourFunction() {
    $('.colour img').greyScale({
    // call the plugin with non-defult fadeTime (default: 400ms)
       fadeTime: 500,
      reverse: false
    });
}
```

Then call it on document ready like:

```
$(function () {
    YourFunction();
});
```

Then in the callback for your AJAX call just call `YourFunction()` again?

Comment: This doesn't appear to work as the $(document).ready(function(){ doesn't get fired again as a result of the on page filtering

Comment: Yeah that's when you'd call the YourFunction() yourself after the page filtering?

Answer (score 0):

you can have two functions and then call them when ever you want it

```
function x()
{
   // fade in the grayscaled images to avoid visual jump
    $('.colour img').hide().fadeIn(1000);
}

function y()
{
   $('.colour img').greyScale({
      // call the plugin with non-defult fadeTime (default: 400ms)
      fadeTime: 500,
      reverse: false
}
```

call them in initial load and after the ajax call